# The object from as.h2o has a little observation in R

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I tried to transform from R data to h2o data using `as.h2o` function.

However, the number of observations ​​transformed by the `as.h2o` function is reduced to 10.

There are a total of 1,000 observations in my data. There are 700 train data and 300 test data. However, using the `as.h2o` function only has 10 observations.

Following is my full and open source code. You can use it. please help me.

Why the data that transformed to h2o data has 10 observation?

```
install.packages("h2o")
library(h2o)
h2o.init(max_mem_size = "10G", nthreads = -1)

df<-read.csv("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/german_credit.csv", header=TRUE)
F=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
for(i in F) df[,i]=as.factor(df[,i])

library(caret)

set.seed(1000)
intrain<-createDataPartition(y=df$Creditability, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
train<-df[intrain, ]
test<-df[-intrain, ]
str(train)
str(test)

h2o_train<-as.h2o(train, destination_frame = "h2o_train")
h2o_test<-as.h2o(test, destination_frame = "h2o_test")
str(h2o_train)
str(h2o_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an oddity of how `str()` displays H2OFrames, rather than an actual problem. If you look in Flow (localhost:54321) or call `nrow()` on the h2o objects, you will see the results you would expect.

Comment: This is a bug in the print-out only.  Look at `nrow(h2o_train)` to validate the size.  I filed a bug report here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4742